# Trouble with hibernate and json

Tags: java, json, hibernate

So i have a user and a client.The user can have multiple clients.But json cannot return a value user.

So i did something like this :

```
    @Column
    private Integer fkIdUser ;
```

But i'm new to hibernate and i'm wondering if this is the right way of doing this. Or do i need to use a class with a many to one annotation but how would i do this with json ?

User class

```
public class User {

    public static User globalUser;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_user")
    private Integer id;


    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
```

Then the Client class

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="tbl_clients")
@Access(value = AccessType.FIELD)
public class Client {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id_client")
    private Integer id;


    /* This works
    @Column
    private Integer fkIdUser ;
    */

    // This does not
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_id_user")
    private User user;
```

I'm using this function in the ClientController to store the client to the database

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addclient",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void addClient(@RequestBody Client client) {    
    clientDao.save(client);
}
```

Comment: And how does json enter in your problem?

Comment: I added the function from the client controller how the json is retrieved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the same name of the column in the `@JoinColumn` name. Since you are using `fkIdUser` as the variable and it works, I suppose this is your column name. Then your mapping should be like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fkIdUser")
private User user;
```

Comment: It does't work i get an mysql exception:  Column 'fk_id_user' cannot be null

Comment: This doesn't make sense, if you didn't mapped `@Column(name="fk_id_user")` in the working example

Comment: Also, json probably is not returning a complete `User` object, but  only its id, causing your problem.

Comment: I indeed only return the user id. but i should return the user instead ? Or can i just return the user id or is this not a good practical

Comment: You can, but you cannot expect the user information to be filled automatically. You need to first find the corresponding User from the database through `EntityManager.find(User.class, userId)` (this can be replaced by any equivalent, depending on the implementation you're using) and set it as your User

Comment: Thanks i will look into this